# SQLGrammarException: user lacks privilege or object not found

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I have a postgres stored function that returns a table, when I tried to call this in my Junit test, it would give me the following exception:

```
SQLGrammarException: user lacks privilege or object not found "function_name"
```

Java:

```
 Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(SELECT * from function_name())
```

The beginning of my stored function looks like :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name()

   RETURNS TABLE(
        userid            BIGINT,
        user_height    DOUBLE PRECISION
    )
AS
```

I checked the property file and it is :

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

any ideas?

Comment: Your unit tests don't use a postgres database, but a HSQL database.

Comment: Is there a way to configure that?

Comment: Configure what? Which database you connect to? Sure it is. Set the URL to your postgres database, and set the dialect to PostgreSQL9Dialect.

Comment: Is it really an `SQLGrammarException`? Hard to believe. Surely an `SQLException`?

Comment: @EJP `SQLGrammarException` is a hibernate wrapper around a `SQLException`